# Selenium IDE - Verifying hidden/visible verification messages?

Tags: ide, selenium, hidden, verification, visible

There's a webpage I'm trying to test that has multiple textboxes. Each textbox has its own specific validation message that is hidden.

Before an incorrect value is entered, I am use **'verifyNotVisible'** in order to confirm that there is no validation message being shown to the user.  This part passes just fine.

Afterwards, I have selenium type in invalid characters to make the validation message show.

The problem I'm having at this point is that while the validation message *is visible* to me, Selenium is still failing at the **'verifyVisible'** line right after entering the invalid characters.

The following is what I have in Selenium:

[image: Selenium IDE Info]
**Full Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5RrH.png

Note that the validation messages are set to hidden prior to having invalid characters entered.  Additionally, both **'assertValue'** and **'verifyTextPresent'** are passing before and after the validation message is being shown.

Does anyone know of a way to have Selenium pass the 'verifyVisible' portion correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to insert an appropriate wait period.  If you are checking `verifyVisible` immediately after inserting your invalid character the modified DOM might not yet be there at the point your comparison is being made.

Take a look, for example, at Selenium's `clickAndWait` to see how to wrap an appropriate pause.